# How To Fix Inconsistent Javascript Code That Fades In/Out Sections On My Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using code that I found in a [javascript fiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/71/) that fades various #divID's in and out of the page based upon in-page navigation used by the viewer.

The Problem I am having is that each button fades in/out the content inconsistently. `btn-one` will fade old content out smoothly and fade in new content smoothly which is exactly what I desire. Buttons two and four will hard-drop old content and fade in new content. Button three will fade out old content but `hard-cut` in new content.

I would like them all to behave the same. If possible I would also like to be able to control the type and duration of each animation that divs utilize.

I've tried direct copy/paste of the fiddle code into my project and it has worked with two divs. Maybe the problem lies in creating additional divs? But this raises further questions because adding more `div`'s into the fiddle itself works just fine.

```
$('#btn-one').click(function(e) {
  $('#reviews, #aboutus').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#splash').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$('#btn-two').click(function(e) {
  $('#splash, #aboutus').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#reviews').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$('#btn-three').click(function(e) {
  $('#splash, #reviews').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#aboutus').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$('#btn-four').click(function(e) {
  $('#splash, #reviews, #aboutus').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#even').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

I would be very much open to one of two outcomes:

1. A solution to the existing code to make things work.
2. An altogether new code solution that would provide better results.

I appreciate any help you can give. Thank you.

Comment: You have four divs, but you're only fading out two of them in the first three button click events handlers. Try including the third selector in the first three.

Comment: You are correct and that is a typo; an oversight in my presentation of the code. Thank you for pointing it out. Unfortunately it is not the cause of the inconsistencies I am observing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control, try using CSS transitions. You can mimic the `fadeIn/Out()` functionality by setting up classes like this:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}
.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then initialize all your buttons with a `.toggle-btn` class, and initialize the divs with the `.fade` class, and on all but the one you want to show include the `.fade-out` and `.hidden` classes (this will start those out hidden). Then attach an event listener (just one to the document, don't need individual ones for each button) like so

```
const toggleBtns = {one: 'splash', two: 'reviews', three: 'aboutUs', four: 'even'}
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // this line cancels the event if it's not a button we want
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('toggle-btn')) return;
  // grab the element(s) we want to hide
  const toFade = $('.fade:not(.fade-out)');
  // add an event listener for the CSS transition that removes after firing
  toFade.one('transitionend', function(tansitionEvent) {
    toFade.addClass('hidden')
  });
  // apply the class which will start the transition
  toFade.addClass('fade-out');
  // remove the invisibility classes from your target element, starting that transition
  $(`#${toggleBtns[e.target.id.split('-')[1]]}`).removeClass('fade-out hidden');
}
```

I've never used `transitionend` with JQuery, but I assume it works. It looks like you want your buttons to only show one thing and hide everything else, so I put the associated div IDs in an object. Then I grab that with `toggleBtns[e.target.id.split('-')[1]]`. You maintain the pattern of `btn-number` for the button IDs, so I'm using `split()` to grab the number, then passing the result of that as the key into the `toggleBtns` object.

Comment: I have limited knowledge and would like clarification on what I should assign to the buttons themselves? I'm certain it's implied in the above solution, but all I have discerned is that I should assign .toggle-btn .fade to my primarily displayed div and .toggle-btn .fade. .fade-out .hidden to all of the secondary 'to be displayed later' divs.

I'm assuming that the above code is fully standalone and works independently from my initial code, correct?

Comment: I realized there was some ambiguity in my answer and updated it. Put .toggle-btn on the buttons, and the other classes on your divs to show/hide.